# Nodejs, Mqtt: Connection and callback order is wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

I want to use the mqtt package for nodejs. Everywhere I look, I find code samples like this one (from official doc on github) :

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt')
const client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org')

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('presence', function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
    }
  })
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer
  console.log(message.toString())
  client.end()
})
```

My problem is that the connection: mqtt.connect() is before the callback: client.on('connect', ...). I think it is the wrong order. From what I understand, we send a CONNECT packet, **then** declare what to do when receiving a CONNACK packet.

This is different from the python package where you instanciate a client, then you declare "on connect" and other callbacks, and only then you use a method client.connect(). From what I understand, you declare what to do when receiving a CONNACK packet, **then** send a CONNECT packet.

Is there a way to guarantee the correct order (like in the python package) ?

**Edit** :
The main concern is that if the CONNACK message comes back very quickly, and the code to declare the "on connect" callback is inside some complicated conditions, the "on connect" callback could not trigger (because the connection is already done) and there will be no client.subscribe, so our client will not be subscribed to the intended topic.

I guess it is theorically possible but practically impossible ? But what if the code is a bit bigger ? I actually played with this a while ago and had a code where sometimes the subscription was made, and other times the subscription was missed, depending on the speed of the CONNACK response I guess. (The code just waited a certain amount of time, maybe 0.1seconds, before declaring the "on connect" callback)

Comment: It actually works because js is asyncronous and the callback declaration will happen before the actual connection. Still, with this wrong order in the code, I find no way to guarantee the correct order in the execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You kind of guessed it right here**

> I guess it is theorically possible but practically impossible

Just that **it's theoretically impossible too** in Javascript.

See, the `connect` method connects to the MQTT server (`test.mosquitto.org` in our case).
And its a IO call which will be executed asynchronously as [Non-Blocking IO](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking) call

So what happens is this,

1. Connection to the MQTT server is triggered in a Non-Blocking IO way
2. Since the IO call is non-blocking, it will move to the next line (registering the `connect` callback)
3. the connection establishment event will be received by the callback registered to `connect` event

So the JS event loop ([read more here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick#event-loop-explained)) will never process the connection established event before registering the `connect` callback, thus ensuring the code always works.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is write on python pack, but if we look on official [Mqtt docks](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718028) correct order is:

1. connect to mqtt server
2. then send command to mqtt server that your client subscribed to some topics
3. and then on our Node layer we add some callback (`client.on('message', console.log)`) to handle incoming messages

**Edit 1** client.on('message', console.log) or client.on('connect', console.log) will work immediately when events was published by EventEmitter

**Edit 2** i will try to describe the 3 points above more verbosely using your code example

```
// try connect to Mqtt server (point 1)
const client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org')

// when connection is done
client.on('connect', function () {
// try to subscribe to some topic (point 2)
  client.subscribe('presence', function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
    }
  })
})

// when we got some message from mqtt we call a callback function (point 3)
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  console.log(message.toString())
  // and close the client
  client.end()
})
```

**Edit 3**
Declaration of "on connect" callback, will be faster than connection.
This mechanic is called [micro and macrotasks](https://javascript.info/event-loop#event-loop).
Try this example in console:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log('connection'), 0)
console.log('add callback')
console.log('add callback')
console.log('add callback')
console.log('add callback')
console.log('add callback')
```

Comment: I don't find the part talking about callbacks in the documentation you provided

Comment: callback is the implementation of the client on Node.js to handle incoming messages.


I brought the documentation above in order to show that at first we connect to the mqtt server and then we indicate to it which topics we want to subscribe.

Comment: I thank you for your answer, but my concern is that the on_connect callback may miss the CONNACK response from the server if the on_connect callback is not yet active, and then the SUBSCRIBE message will not be sent. I edited my question to make that more clear.

Comment: The code in my question (from official doc on github for the node mqtt package) doesn't follow your 3 points : it sends the SUBSCRIBE message conditionally on the CONNACK response (from what I understand) and it is a good idea, but the condition is activated after sending the CONNECT message (from what I understand) and this worries me.

Comment: As shown with your second edit, the point 2 is inside the "on_connect" callback, so the subscription part is not garanteed. I think that it is possible that the subscription part will be skipped if the connection event (published by EventEmitter) happens before the callback is active. If you look at the order of the code, it is even strange that the connection event happens after the "on connect" declaration.

Comment: just because part of the subscription is inside the "connect" message, which is why the subscription is guaranteed. If connection is lost and subsctribe method, has no confirmation from mqtt server, it will throw an error. And when it connect again, again will call calback function, and try to subscribe again

Comment: As said in the question, first we connect, then we declare the "on connect" callback. I think it is the wrong order, and your answer doesn't adress that imho.

Comment: declaration of "on connect" callback, will be faster than connection i'll add simple example to my answer